# Mod_rewrite pretty url when domain/foo is a directory

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, directory

Starting with something as simple as:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

What if I also want the following to work:

```
RewriteRule ^/foo$ /index.php?page=foo #/foo IS a directory
```

This seem to work ONLY if the R flag is set, but then the full non-pretty url is written.
Thus it seems I can REDIRECT existing directory, but not rewrite them... Maybe with an .htaccess inside the directory itself? Or some PHP magic in /foo/index.php like header(/index.php?page=foo)? Will it work? Will it be HTTP standard/search engine optimized?

Please help!

PS: The oddest idea occurred to me: redirecting /foo to /not-a-dir, and then rewriting /not-a-dir to /index.php?p=foo should theorically work... But... Come on... Really?!?

Comment: why do you need the /foo directory anyway ?
are there any content inside you need to access by url such /foo/something ?

Answer (score 1):

There's an option to mod_rewrite to make it handle directories instead of passing them to mod_dir:

```
RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash
```

There's more information about this at [the apache documentation site](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions).